# How to rotate text in pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to rotate the double angle bracket set as the content in an `:after` pseudo-element using the css `transform` value `rotate(90deg)` for a tab across the top of the screen. Here's the relevant code:

```css
.header {
  -moz-transition: top .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
  -o-transition: top .5s ease;
  transition: top .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -60px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #2d2;
}

.header.in-top {
  top: 0;
}

.header-tab {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease;
  -o-transition: color .5s ease;
  transition: color .5s ease;
}

.header-tab:hover {
  color: #e22;
}

.header-arrow:after {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.header .header-arrow:after {
  content: "\00bb";
}

.header.in-top .header-arrow:after {
  content: "\00ab";
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-tab" data-toggle="in-top">
    <span class="header-arrow"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `data-toggle` attribute is used in JavaScript to toggle the `in-top` class in order to switch the direction of the double angle bracket as well as to expose the content of the header by bringing it down. The `transform` properties I have specified seem to do nothing though. Any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on the pseudo-element. Alternatively, `inline-table` or `block` should also work.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6FTa/).

Your pseudo-element is displayed `inline` by default, which makes it a nontransformable element. From the [CSS Transforms Working Draft specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/):

> **transformable element**
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>   an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’, ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or ‘table-caption’

Comment: Thank you, works great! And you're the first to answer, so kudos.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the pseudo-element as a block or inline-block element:

```
.header-arrow:after {
  display: block;
}
```

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/) says rotation should work on inline elements, but in WebKit based browsers it doesn't works: https://www.webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/

Comment: I just read the same specification and it should *not* work on inline elements, did I miss something?

Comment: I think *[atomic inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13)* are also inline elements.

Comment: I can understand why that's confusing because the wording of the spec for the definition of *atomic inline-level elements* can definitely be written better. However from my understanding from the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model), atomic inline-level elements cannot be split into multiple lines/boxes, which disqualifies `display: inline` and explains why the transformation wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate property will apply on pseudo-element(after/before) only when you will use `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline-block;` property in your class or selector.

```
.className:before{
   -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotateZ(180deg); /* Standard syntax */
    display: inline-block;
}
```